# Update UITableView while scrolling

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

My data source for a UITableView is updated automatically each 5 seconds - this causes some issues when the users is scrolling and the data has changed (less rows etc.)

How is the best approach for handling this? How can I only perform updates when the user is not scrolling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are working with a `UITableView` it is likely that you are already implementing the `UITableViewDelegate` to fill the table with data.

The protocol `UITableViewDelegate` conforms to `UIScrollViewDelegate`, so all you need to do is to implement the methods `-scrollViewWillBeginDragging` and `-scrollViewDidScroll`

So your code should look something like this:

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if (scrollView == self.tableView){
       //your code when user is scrolling
    }
    else
    {
      //your code when user is not scrolling
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that a timer is firing the update. But I have now implemented scrollViewWillBeginDragging and scrollViewDidEndDragging to pause/resume the timer. Thank you, tnylee!

Answer (score 0):

UITableView is also UIScrollView. Ur UIViewController child could be set as UIScrollView delegate and handle method so u can detect if user is scrolling or not.
If u want to reload data in UITableView just call reloadData method